# Remove legend on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, gis, leaflet

I have a leaflet map set to change styles based on a category when a user clicks a button.

Live map: http://maneesha.github.io/test_map.html

Source code: https://github.com/maneesha/maneesha.github.io

There is a legend for each style.
My problem is I can't get the old legend to disappear when another button is clicked (or that button is clicked again). So you'll see on the map each time you click, a new legend appears.

Putting

```
map.removeControl(legend);
```

in the click function does not work and 
results in this in the js console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeFrom' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Repos above have been changed.  Live site no longer exists; source code is at https://github.com/maneesha/leaflet_map_with_styles_and_legends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the variable `legend` in the handler function of the `click` event on `change-gender`. If you do that, `legend` will only be available in that function. If you declare `var legend;` before the click handler and then in the click handler change: `var legend = L.control({position: 'topright'});` to `legend = L.control({position: 'topright'});` legend will be available in the global scope so you can reach it from every function within the global scope.

This won't work:

```
document.getElementById('change-gender').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var genderLegend = L.control({'position': 'topright'}).addTo(map);
});

console.log(genderLegend) // returns undefined
```

This will:

```
var genderLegend;

document.getElementById('change-gender').addEventListener('click', function () {
    genderLegend = L.control({'position': 'topright'}).addTo(map);
});

console.log(genderLegend) // returns the legend instance
```

Comment: Thanks - I think that did it.  One other thing in case anyone else stumbles upon this question:  I put  `map.removeControl(legend);`  before  `legend.addTo(map)` so any existing legend would be removed before creating a new one.  So I had to not just initialize `var legend;` but I actually had to create the legend so that there would be one to remove.

Comment: You don't have to create an `L.Control` instance when declaring your variable. If you're not going to need it, why do so? You could simply wrap your `map.removeControl(legend)` in an `if` statement which checks if `legend` is actual an instance of `L.Control`. For example: `if (legend instanceof L.Control) { map.removeControl(legend); }`

Comment: You're right - I tried that first but didn't have the conditional quite right so I didn't think it would work but now I do. Thanks!