# Leaflet update WMS legend on change

Tags: jquery, leaflet, legend, wms

I have a dropdown that changes the SLD of a WMS layer.

Now, I want the legend to be updated according to this change. Finally, the legend must display the selected SLD of the layer.

The problem is that every time I change my choice with the dropdown, the legend is added to the map. But I want the legend to be refreshed.

[image: See this example]

For example on this image, I chose '**demo_secteur_statut_**' then '**demo_secteur_statut**' then '**demo_secteur_statut_**'

I think we need to remove layer and/or legend before adding it but my attempts don’t work.

JS

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "sld.json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);

     $('#select-sld').empty();
     $('#select-sld').append("<option value='0'>-- Choisir une analyse --</option>");
     $.each(data, function(i, item) {
         $('#select-sld').append('<option value=' + data[i].id + '>' + data[i].nom + '</option>');
     });

     ////// SLD DROPDOWN (nom = name of SLD on GeoServer)

     $("#select-sld").change(function(){
            var selectId = $("#select-sld option:selected").val();
            var getSLD = [];

            for (var i in data){     
                if(data[i].id == selectId){  
                    getSLD += data[i].nom;
                    if(data[i].id != selectId){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            };
            secteur.setParams({styles: getSLD});

            ////// LEGEND

            var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

            legend.onAdd = function (map2) {

                var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
                var url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=cite:demo_secteur&STYLE='+getSLD;

                div.innerHTML += '<img src='+url+' alt="legend" width="75" height="55">';
            return div;
            };
        legend.addTo(map2);
        }); 
  },
  complete: function() {}
});

///////////////////////////////////////// 

var map2 = L.map('map2', { zoomControl:false, attributionControl:false }).setView([48.11, -1.67], 14);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map2);

var secteur = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms", {
layers: 'cite:demo_secteur',
format: 'image/png',
transparent: true
});

secteur.addTo(map2);
```

HTML

```
<div id="container-map">
    <div id="map2"></div>    
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for help

**{
EDIT
}**

Solution found, thks to : [them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265730/remove-legend-on-leaflet-map)

> You could simply wrap your map.removeControl(legend) in an if
>   statement which checks if legend is actual an instance of L.Control.

So it gives that, hoping it helps someone

```
var legend;

$("#select-sld").change(function(){
    var selectId = $("#select-sld option:selected").val();
    var getSLD = [];

    for (var i in data){     
        if(data[i].id == selectId){  
            getSLD += data[i].nom;
            if(data[i].id != selectId){
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    secteur.setParams({styles: getSLD});
    console.log(secteur.wmsParams.styles);

    $('#result-select-sld').html(getSLD);

    if(legend instanceof L.Control){map2.removeControl(legend);}

    legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

    legend.onAdd = function (map2) {
        var div = [];
        div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=cite:demo_secteur&STYLE='+getSLD;
        div.innerHTML += '<img src='+url+' alt="legend" width="75" height="55">';

        return div;     

    };

    legend.addTo(map2);

});
```